# Decoding unnamed JSON container in swift

Tags: arrays, json, swift, api, decode

Having a hard time decoding this JSON with an unnamed container. Not sure how to define the struct. I want to store these objects, but for now getting them to print would work. When I examine their paths they follow a (0.name, 1.name, 2.name, etc) pattern. But obviously using numbers won't work in the struct. Never had this problem before, as most of the JSON objects I've worked with have labeled containers. How do I decode this?

```
[
    {
        "lotCode": "XYZ",
        "name": "Example Lot",
        "style": null,
        "mapLink": "https://maps.---.edu/#/?",
        "percentAvailable": 0.74
    },
    {
        "lotCode": "ABC",
        "name": "Example Lot 2",
        "style": null,
        "mapLink": "https://maps.---.edu/#/?",
        "percentAvailable": 0.91999996
    },
    {
        "lotCode": "DEF",
        "name": "Example Lot 3",
        "style": null,
        "mapLink": "https://maps.---.edu/#/?",
        "percentAvailable": 0.95
    }]




    func performRequest(){
    if let url = URL(string: urlString){
        let session = URLSession(configuration: .default)
        let task = session.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
            if(error != nil){
                self.delegate?.didFailWithError(error: error!)
                return
            }
            
            if let safeData = data {
                if let parkingData = parseJSON(safeData){
                    print(parkingData[0].name)
                }
            }
        }
        task.resume()
    }
}

func parseJSON(_ data : Data) -> ParkingData? {
    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
    do{
        let decodedData = try decoder.decode(ParkingData.self, from: data)
        parkingData = ParkingData(parkingList: parkingArray)
        return parkingData
    } catch {
        print(error)
        return nil
    }
}


struct ParkingData : Codable {
   let parkingList : [Deck]
}

struct Deck : Codable {
   let lotCode: String
   let name: String
   let style: String
   let mapLink: String
   let percentAvailable: Double
}
```

Comment: How about just decoding a `[Deck].self`?

Comment: Yes, it’s just an array.  What’s the issue?

Comment: @matt Yeah, I understand it's an array. However, the problem is I'm having difficulty defining it in the struct to decode it. Are you saying I don't need to decode it, since it's an array?

Comment: @Sweeper I commented out the other struct and just decoded "Deck" without the array signs and after returning a deck object and printing it I get this error: "typeMismatch(Swift.Dictionary<Swift.String, Any>, Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "Expected to decode Dictionary<String, Any> but found an array instead.", underlyingError: nil))"

Comment: @Sweeper when I try to decode [Deck].self like you suggested and print this out in the same function to test: print(decodedData[0].name), I get this error:

valueNotFound(Swift.String, Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [_JSONKey(stringValue: "Index 0", intValue: 0), CodingKeys(stringValue: "style", intValue: nil)], debugDescription: "Expected String value but found null instead.", underlyingError: nil))

Comment: Even tried looping through with a for loop, and printing the objects individually that way, but still end up getting the above error "valueNotFound"

Comment: @FaisalSalad just replace `let style: String` with `var style: String?` in your `Deck` struct and try again to decode your data as `[Deck].self`.

Comment: @gcharita it worked! I've got all the parking deck names printing in a loop! Thanks everyone. I guess the problem was not making the properties optional to handle the null values. Appreciate the help everyone ! Wish I could upvote your answers.